# Facebook sharing when user revoked access for the app

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to handle an error that could be caused on sharing to Facebook when user revoked access to my app via Facebook settings page.

Facebook documentation says:

> However, note that this doesn't account for the situation where the
>   user may have revoked access to your app or if the user has changed
>   their password. You will need to always look out for the invalid
>   access_token and redirect the user to re-authorize your app. For
>   invalid access token, the following error is returned in the
>   'response' parameter of the onComplete() method:

My code:

```
facebook.dialog(activity, "feed", params, new DialogListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e)
    {
        Log.printMethod();
        showErrorToast(activity, e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(DialogError e)
    {
        Log.printMethod();
        showErrorToast(activity, e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values)
    {
        Log.printMethod();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel()
    {   
        Log.printMethod();
    }
});
```

**The problem with that any of these method don't get called**, so I can't get a clue that user has revoked permissions and I need to ask him to authorize again.

Instead user sees something like this in a webview. Any ideas? 
[image]

Comment: These methods get called when the user has completed (or aborted) the login flow and your app is called back. The screenshot shows what? - is this a user trying to log in again after they've revoked previous permissions? (I ask because this looks more like a misconfigured app or login call)

Answer (score 1):

Check the user's permissions first:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#checking

REST:

> https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/permissions?access_token=APP_TOKEN
>   https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=USER_TOKEN

JS:

```
FB.api('/me/permissions', function(response) {
    var perms = response.data[0];
    if ('publish_actions' in perms && perms.publish_actions === 1) {
        // send
    }
}
```

Example response:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "installed": 1,
            "basic_info": 1,
            "email": 1,
            "publish_actions": 1,
            "user_friends": 1
        }
    ]
}
```